# ORA-01013 - Weblogic setting error?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, weblogic

I am running a banking program, coded in Oracle PL/SQL. This program runs for 2-3 hours everyday, as part of the End of Day processing.

Till yesterday, it was working fine. Today when I run it today, after around 30 mins, the program terminates with the error `ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation`. I am not terminating the program manually.

I feel this could be a weblogic (where the application is deployed) setting problem. I am not fluent in weblogic and am not sure what parameter can be changed to stop this error. Please help!!!

Oracle version: 11.2.0.3
Oracle weblogic server: 11g

Comment: Sounds like a database timeout problem.  There should be some logs in your WebLogic server directory's `logs` directory.  There might be a Java stack trace that shows the details of what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a JDBC timeout. From the WebLogic console go to Services->Data Sources and click the name of your data source to see its settings. Click the Connection Pool tab, and expand the Advanced section at the bottom of the page. Look for the [Statement Timeout setting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JDBCjdbcdatasourcesjdbcdatasourceconfigconnectionpooltitle.html#StatementTimeout).

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13737/ds_tuning.htm#i1200192):

> When Statement Timeout is set to -1, (the default) statements do not timeout.

The behaviour you're seeing suggests the timeout is set to 1800 if it's timing out after 30 minutes.

However, this won't have changed on its own, and if it was already set then it was being ignored previously, which would need some investigation - has anything else changed?

Another possibility is that your code is making several calls within the 3-4 hour window and one of them is now exceeding the timeout on its own, which might be the case if the timeout is lower than 1800. Without seeing your code or the current timeout value I'm just guessing, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I shall set this timeout to -1 and check.